# Double Tap Issue Navigation

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, nav, flexslider

I created a responsive navigation menu, but on tablets, it has the "double tap" issue. When you tap the main heading, it reloads the page before you can click a sub-heading. I've tried a few jquery plug-ins, but they make the Flexslider below my navigation bar not show (I don't know if they hide it or what happens). Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Codepen: http://codepen.io/caguilera0001/pen/jrBgdG 
(my flex slider does not show in code pen, unfortunately)

```js
 $(window).load(function() {
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     directionNav: false,
     slideshowSpeed: 4000,
   });
 });


 //to hide the control arrows 
 $('#carousel-home').flexslider({
   animation: "slide",
   controlNav: false,
   animationLoop: false,
   slideshow: false,
   itemWidth: 170,
   itemMargin: 5,
   asNavFor: '#slider',
   start: function(slider) {
       //HIDE THE ARROWS BY DEFAULT...
       $('#slider .flex-direction-nav').css({
         visibility: 'hidden'
       });

       //THEN INSERT YOUR CUSTOM JQUERY CLICK ACTIONS TO REVEAL THEM AGAIN
       slider.find('a').on('click', function() {
         $('#slider .flex-direction-nav').css({
           visibility: 'visible'
         });
       });
     } //end start function
 }); //end carousel

 $('#slider').flexslider({
   slidshow: false,
   animation: "slide",
   controlNav: false,
   animationLoop: false,
   slideshow: true,
   sync: "#carousel-home"
 }); //end slider
```

```css
a {
  -webkit-transition: color .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: color .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: color .3s ease;
  -o-transition: color .3s ease;
  transition: color .3s ease;
}
a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /** add this **/
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /** add this **/
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /** add this **/
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  /** add this **/
  background-color: #4484CE;
}
#nav > a {
  display: none;
  z-index: 99;
}
#nav li {
  position: relative;
}
#nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
/* first level */

#nav > ul {
  height: 30px;
  /* 60 */
  background-color: #93C178;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav > ul > li {
  width: 12.5%;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  /* 60 (24) */
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #4484CE;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > a,
#nav > ul:not( :hover) > li.active > a {
  background-color: #F9CF00;
}
/* second level */

#nav li ul {
  background-color: #93C178;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#nav li:not( :first-child):hover ul {
  left: -1px;
}
#nav li ul a {
  font-size: 14px;
  /* 20 */
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #4484CE;
  padding: 0.75em;
  /* 15 (20) */
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #4484CE;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover,
#nav li ul:not( :hover) li.active a {
  background: #FCFCFC;
  color: #465C8B;
}
////Flexslider Css////
@font-face {
  font-family: 'flexslider-icon';
  src: url('flex slider /fonts/flexslider-icon.eot');
  src: url('flex slider /fonts/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('flex slider /fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'), url('flex slider /fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('flex slider /fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
     * RESETS
     * ====================================================================================================================*/

.flex-container a:hover,
.flex-slider a:hover {
  outline: none;
}
.slides,
.slides > li,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.flex-pauseplay span {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
     * BASE STYLES
     * ====================================================================================================================*/

.flexslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides > li {
  display: none;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
.flexslider .slides:after {
  content: "\0020";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
html[xmlns] .flexslider .slides {
  display: block;
}
* html .flexslider .slides {
  height: 1%;
}
.no-js .flexslider .slides > li:first-child {
  display: block;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
     * DEFAULT THEME
     * ====================================================================================================================*/

.flexslider {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  border: 4px solid #4484CE;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -o-box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: '' 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides {
  zoom: 1;
}
.flexslider .slides img {
  height: auto;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}
.flex-viewport {
  max-height: 2000px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.loading .flex-viewport {
  max-height: 300px;
}
.carousel li {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f001';
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
  content: '\f002';
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -50px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-align: right;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
  z-index: -1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000;
}
.flex-pauseplay a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f004';
}
.flex-pauseplay a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-pauseplay a.flex-play:before {
  content: '\f003';
}
.flex-control-nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li {
  margin: 0 6px;
  display: none;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
}
.flex-control-paging li a {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  display: block;
  background: #666;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active {
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-control-thumbs {
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-control-thumbs li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  opacity: .7;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next,
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev {
  display: none;
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next,
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next {
  display: none;
}
/* ====================================================================================================================
     * RESPONSIVE
     * ====================================================================================================================*/

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 10px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .flexslider {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav" role="navigation"> <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a>  <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>

  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li><a href="/"><span>About Us</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="principal's_message.html">Principal's Message</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="mission_and_vision.html">Mission and Vision</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="our_history.html">Our History</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="staff_directory.html">Staff Directory</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="links.html">Links</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="photo_gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li> <a href="/"><span>School Offices</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="attendance_office.html">Attendance</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="counseling_office.html">Counseling</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="main_office.html">Main</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="magnet_office.html">Magnet</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="bridge_office.html">Bridge</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="english_learner's_office.html">EL</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="itd_office.html">ITD</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="library.html">Library</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="parent_center.html">Parent Center</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="nurse's_office.html">Nurse</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="safety_ofifice.html">Safety</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="plant_manager's_office.html">Plant Manager</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="cafeteria.html">Cafeteria</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="student_store.html">Student Store</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li> <a href="/"><span>Academics</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="departments.html">Departments</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="counseling_office.html">Counseling</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="library.html">Library</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li> <a href="/"><span>Programs</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com" target="new">IB</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="middle_years_programme.html">The Middle Years</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="ste[+a]m_program.html">STE[+a]M</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="performing_arts_program.html">Performing Arts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="vei-jv.html">VEI-JV</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="gate_sas_program.html">GATE/SAS</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://lacerstars.org/" target="new">LACER</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li> <a href="/"><span>Students</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="dress_code.html">Dress Code</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="cougar_code.html">Cougar Code</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="attendance_policy.html">Attendance Policy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.bancroftib.weebly.com/learner-profile.html" target="new">IB Learner Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">Student Handbook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="library.html">Library</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="map.html">Map</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://achieve.lausd.net/site/default.aspx?PageType=3&ModuleInstanceID=1555&ViewID=7B97F7ED-8E5E-4120-848F-A8B4987D588F&RenderLoc=0&FlexDataID=16590&PageID=845" target="new">Food Menu</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="student_store.html">Student Store</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.bancroftmiddleschool.org/2015-16yearbook/index.html" target="new">Yearbook</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li> <a href="/"><span>Parents</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="parent_bulletin.html">Parent Bulletin</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="cougar_news.html">Cougar News</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="parent_center.html">Parent Center</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="bell_schedule.html">Bell Schedule</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="classes_homework.html">Classes/Homework</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="culmination_requirements.html">Culmination</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://achieve.lausd.net/cms/lib08/CA01000043/Centricity/Domain/317/24359_OSO_PrntStdntHndbk1516_eng.pdf" target="new">District Handbook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="school_site_council.html">SSC Council</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="school_decision_making_council.html">SDM Council</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="elac.html">ELAC</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact_teachers.html">Contact Teachers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Anything else I should add just let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `href`'s of the anchors in the parent `<li>`s are causing an issue. Using `href="/"`, as you have found, reloads the page. I use `href="#"` when I have subnavigation. This causes another issue (though fixable!): clicking/touching it will take you to the top of the current page. However, a little bit of jQuery will solve this:

```
$('.has-subnav a').on('click touchstart', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

For your subnavigation, I'd suggest putting a class on the parent `<li>` and changing the `href="/"` to `href="#"`:

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation"> <a href="#nav" title="Show navigation">Show navigation</a> <a href="#" title="Hide navigation">Hide navigation</a>

<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

    <li class="has-subnav"><a href="#"><span>About Us</span></a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="principal's_message.html">Principal's Message</a></li> 
        <li><a href= "mission_and_vision.html">Mission and Vision</a></li> 
        <li><a href= "our_history.html">Our History</a></li> 
        <li><a href= "staff_directory.html">Staff Directory</a></li> 
        <li><a href= "links.html">Links</a></li> 
        <li><a href= "photo_gallery.html">Photo Gallery</a></li> 
</ul>
</li>
... etc
```

---

If you're looking for more info on the jQuery snippet above, [you can read the jQuery docs here about the Event Object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). In the example above, the Event Object is referenced by the `e` in `function(e)...`.

Comment: Wow thanks, this sounds great! I'll look into this and try this.

Comment: @Citlalipop: did you find a solution?

Comment: I've been so busy lately, because I'm still in school, so I haven't had the time. Hopefully I can get to it today. I'll keep you updated

Comment: this works, but hides my flex slider plugin below my navigation bar. Any reason why that would be?

Comment: so if you remove the code I've suggested, the flexslider functions as expected? Also - the HTML code i've given above is truncated for brevity's sake. If you paste it in as is, it will break other elements.

Comment: Yes, for some reason it hides my flexslider. And yes, I added the class to each dropdown with sub-headings, the # instead of /, and the jquery script.

Comment: unless the issue can be recreated or seen, I can't debug it.

Comment: yeah, the problem is flexslider wont show in the code snippet when it is run, nor in code pen. Any ideas on how else I can show it?

Comment: when I copied the css I inserted above in my post, the border is on top of the drop-downs on the hover effects despite having a lower z-index. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: @Citlalipop, while that might be a case for a different question, it is because you have a `border-top` rule in your CSS.

Comment: I set the z-index to -1 on the flexslider class and I fixed it. Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article: [CSS-only Dropdowns with the Checkbox Hack](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/08/quick-tip-css-only-dropdowns-with-the-checkbox-hack/). If you can change your main headings over to checkboxes and use the technique described in the article you will eliminate the "double-tap" issue on mobile.

You can also work in a CSS `:hover` if you don't want to force users to click the main headings to get the drop-down in "desktop mode" but let them hover the mouse instead. Just be sure to wrap it in a media query so it's not picked up by the mobile browsers and potentially cause the "double-tap" problem again!

Comment: Wow thank you, that sounds like a really good solution, I would have never thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: If I were to do this, would my checkbox have the same CSS as my other headings? How would I reformat my CSS?

Comment: The `label` associated with the checkbox can have similar CSS formatting (it's just an HTML element, similar in formatting capability to an anchor). Of course you want to hide the actual checkbox so you'll want to add a `#nav > ul > li > input[type='checkbox'] { display: none; }` to hide that. The really nice thing about this alternate solution is that you can do everything with CSS and eliminate the JavaScript animations and event-handlers for your menu.

Comment: Cool, thank you so much! I'll try this out as soon as I can

Comment: I'm having some trouble implementing this into my code. Could you possible make a codepen or some type of fiddle to show me how to input it properly? Thanks

Comment: And I do have my code set to hover and not click, and that works on a desktop screen. Can you further explain how to make the media query to eliminate the problem in mobile view?

Comment: I'll put a codepen together for you, but you'll have to give me a couple days to carve out the time.

Comment: hey, just wondering if you have had the time yet to make a copeen.

Comment: Hope everything is going ok. No worries if you have forgotten about this post, I understand. I would really appreciate that codepen, because everytime I try and implement this, I run into trouble. Thanks!